# Register a generic type inside an assembly that implements an interface with autofac

Tags: c#, generics, dependency-injection, autofac

Inside the project `Providers` I have defined this class

```
public class MyLogProvider<T> : IMyProvider<T>
    where T : ILoggable
```

`ILoggable` is a simple interface with no methods to implement.

Then, I have a web project with some MVC Controllers that implement the interface `ILoggable`.
For example

```
public class MyController : Controller, ILoggable
{
    ...
}
```

Finally I have a project `IoC` that is referenced by the web project and that references the project `Providers`. So inside `IoC` I cannot use `MyController` class.

I need to do this kind of registration:

```
builder.RegisterType<MyLogProvider<MyController>>()
    .As<IMyProvider<MyController>>()
    .InstancePerRequest();
```

but obviusly I cannot do in that way...

I have also tried with

```
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(Log4NetProvider<>)).As(typeof(Log4NetProvider<>));
```

and I have looked for to use

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assemblies)
```

but with no success.

Comment: You register the class alone and not the interface. I assume the interface is what is injected into the controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You register the class alone and not the interface.

```
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(MyProvider<>)).As(typeof(IMyProvider<>));
```

I assume the interface is what is injected into the controller

```
public class MyController : Controller, ILoggable {
    public MyController (IMyProvider<MyController> provider) {
        //...
    }
}
```